# A phrase for "Turning a match around" kind

Tags: phrase-requests

I wanted to know a phrase for the purpose of the doing of an event which is unlikely to happened. Like if a football match is being lost by team A by a huge margin, something like "It's X's time to rise and shine. Can he flip all the coins/turn against the odds...?" A phrase to suit that purpose.

Comment: Aside: "[**rise and shine**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Rise+and+Shine)" is generally used with reference to getting out of bed.

Comment: What don't you like about the expression in the title? "Is it X's moment to shine? Can he turn the match around, against all odds?"

Comment: I agree with Weather Vane, you already have two possible answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word or phrase for turning the tide against a rival in a competition in the last moments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516236/word-or-phrase-for-turning-the-tide-against-a-rival-in-a-competition-in-the-last)

Comment: I would say "striking the wrong end of the match".